# ArcMap "clip to shape" analogue for basemaps in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clip, qgis-2.18

Is there any function in QGIS like ArcMap's **Clip to shape**?

I want to clip **base map** like in ArcMap (below)

[image]

In QGIS with the same shape (below)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is Raster - Extraction - Clip raster by a mask layer.

Things to keep in mind:

1. It is important that your mask layer and target raster should be in the same coordinate system
2. It is not possible to clip WMS basemaps. You can only do it with proper raster like .TIF
3. Another option is to create a big polygon, make it opaque and clip a hole inside with your target layer. See example in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6h5kT2--xBM)

Comment: So we can say that QGIS can't do what I asked, I wanted to clip WMS basemap like in ArcMap. Anyway thanks for your answer @Basile.